# break-inside: avoid-column; // not working

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to achieve two columns of text, though I want to control how and where in the text the columns break.
I have...

```css
body {
}

#content {
    column-count: 2;
}

#left_col {
        break-inside:avoid-column;
}

#right_col {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="winning_grunfeld_styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<header><h1>1 Exchange Variation</h1></header>
    
<div id = "content">
<div id = "left_col">
    <p>
        In current practice, the main line<br>
        of the Grunfeld Defense is the<br>
        Exchange Variation, beginning<br>
    </p>
        
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>d4</td><td>f6</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>c4</td><td>g6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>Nc3</td><td>d5 (1)</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;White's first and most natural<br>
        reaction is acceptance of Black's<br>
        intention by<br>
    </p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>cd</td><td>Nxd5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td><td>e4</td><td>Nxc3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td><td>bc</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <p>
    occupying the centre. This is the<br>
    starting position of the Exchange<br>
    Variation and of the material to<br>
    be discussed in this chapter.<br>
    </p>
</div><!-- end of left_col -->

<div id = "right_col">
    <p>
    According to classical principles,<br>
    White should stand better. This<br>
    </p>
    
</div><!-- end of right_col -->
</div><!-- end of content -->
</body>

</html>
```

This is not working correctly as the last few lines of the "left_col" div are being printed on the right side of the screen
(i.e. the right column... 0_0)

The text "Variation and of the material to be discussed in this chapter."
lies within the "left_col" div, which is set to CSS
"break-inside:avoid-column", yet it appears at the top of the second column.
Strange indeed. Any suggestions as to why this is?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are cleaner ways to separate the content into two columns if they are already in two containers, but to answer your question, the property you are looking for in this specific case is to use `break-after: column;` instead of `break-inside:avoid-column;`

```
body {
}

#content {
    column-count: 2;
}

#left_col {
    break-after: column;
}

#right_col {
}
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thanks for the help!